# Zero Point of LMS400

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyone who use LMS400 laser scan system, I want to hown how to detemine the zero point of LMS400, which userguide of LMS400 does not show clearly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59651/zero-point-of-lms400/) by [saddddddd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3927/saddddddd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The zero point is documented in the manual: http://www.sick-automation.ru/images/File/pdf/DIV05/manual%20LMS400.pdf Has a diagram on page 57

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0